Keycloak: Angular 17 app logs out whenever I refresh the page
I'm facing an issue in my Angular 17 application integrated with Keycloak for authentication. The application is using keycloak-angular and keycloak-js libraries to manage authentication and protect routes via a custom AuthGuard extending KeycloakAuthGuard. The login flow works correctly initially, but whenever a user refreshes the page, they are unexpectedly redirected to the Keycloak login page, despite having a valid token stored in local storage.
Can someone please let me know what might be causing this issue?
Angular cli - 17.3.8
Node.js - v18.16.0
keycloak-angular: "^15.3.0",
keycloak-js: "^23.0.7",
Can someone please let me know what might be causing this issue? is it angular code or keycloak configuration?
appconfig.ts:
import { APP_INITIALIZER, ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideAnimationsAsync } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations/async';
import { provideHttpClient, withInterceptors } from '@angular/common/http';
import { hitlInterceptor } from './core/interceptors/hitl.interceptor';
import { provideToastr } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { AuthService } from './core/services/auth.service';
import { initializeKeycloak } from './core/keycloak_init/keycloak-init.factory';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([hitlInterceptor])),
    provideAnimationsAsync(),
    provideToastr(),
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService],
    },
    AuthService,
    KeycloakService,
  ],
};

auth guard:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  Router,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
} from '@angular/router';
import { KeycloakAuthGuard, KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class authGuard extends KeycloakAuthGuard {
  constructor(
    protected override readonly router: Router,
    protected readonly keycloak: KeycloakService
  ) {
    super(router, keycloak);
  }

  public async isAccessAllowed(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ) {
    if (!this.authenticated) {
      await this.keycloak.login({
        redirectUri: window.location.origin + state.url,
      });
    }
    // return true;
    // Get the roles required from the route.
    const requiredRoles = route.data['roles'];
    // Allow the user to proceed if no additional roles are required to access the route.
    if (!Array.isArray(requiredRoles) || requiredRoles.length === 0) {
      return true;
    }
    // Allow the user to proceed if all the required roles are present.
    return requiredRoles.every((role) => this.roles.includes(role));
  }
}

keycloak.init.ts:
import { KeycloakService, KeycloakEventType } from 'keycloak-angular';
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js';
function storeTokens(keycloakInstance: Keycloak) {
  if (keycloakInstance.token) {
    localStorage.setItem(`keycloak_token`, keycloakInstance.token);
  }
  if (keycloakInstance.refreshToken) {
    localStorage.setItem(
      `keycloak_refreshToken`,
      keycloakInstance.refreshToken
    );
  }
}

export function initializeKeycloak(
  keycloak: KeycloakService
): () => Promise<boolean> {
  return (): Promise<boolean> =>
    new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        await keycloak.init({
          config: {
      
            url: 'http://cs.com/keycloak/auth',
            realm: 'realm',
            clientId: 'frontend',
          },
          initOptions: {
            onLoad: 'check-sso',
            silentCheckSsoRedirectUri:
              window.location.origin + '/assets/silent-check-sso.html',
          },
          enableBearerInterceptor: true,
          bearerExcludedUrls: ['/assets'],
        });

        const keycloakInstance = keycloak.getKeycloakInstance();
        const isLoggedIn = await keycloak.isLoggedIn();

        if (isLoggedIn) {
          storeTokens(keycloakInstance);
        } else {
          await keycloak.login();
          storeTokens(keycloakInstance);
        }

        keycloak.keycloakEvents$.subscribe({
          next: (event) => {
            if (event.type === KeycloakEventType.OnAuthRefreshSuccess) {
              storeTokens(keycloakInstance);
            }
          },
        });

        resolve(true);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Keycloak initialization failed', error);
        reject(error);
      }
    });
}


Open your console drawer, you will probably get an error right before being redirected to the keycloak login page. You will probably need to check the preserve log checkbox

not getting console errors in browser , used preserve log checkbox
